# You have to discard, but have no cards in your hand

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I play a spell that makes an opponent discard a card, but they have no cards in their hand, would they have to discard those cards from their library, or would nothing happen?

Answer (score 13):

Nothing happens.

---

He is instructed to discard a card.

> 701.7a To discard a card, move it from its owner’s hand to that player’s graveyard.

It's impossible for him to discard a card, so he does as much as possible.

> 609.3. If an effect attempts to do something impossible, it does only as much as possible.

It does not affect him.

Comment: Note: As you can see from the definition of "discard", the phrase "discard from a library" makes no sense. You can move a card from a library, but you cannot discard from it.